# How's this undeclared variable working and assuming another's role?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm following this guide "thejsway" from GitHub and this lesson is about element animation.

This code was provided by the author, but I can't figure out how and why the variable "block" in this line: 
`'block.style.left = (xBlock + movement) + "px" '` is doing the work of the variable blockElement from        `const blockElement = document.getElementById("block");` which I assume it's a reference to the same element?

Shouldn't it be `blockElement`, instead of `block`? How is it even working when `block` isn't declared anywhere?

Whole code:

```
    <body>
        <div id="frame">
            <div id="block"></div>
        </div>
           <script>

            const moveBlock = () => {

                const xBlock = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(block).left);

                // is this block the same as blockElement? how?
                block.style.left = (xBlock + movement) + "px";

                requestAnimationFrame(moveBlock);
            };

            const frameElement = document.getElementById("frame");
            const blockElement = document.getElementById("block");

            const movement = 7;

            requestAnimationFrame(moveBlock);
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: `block` get its value from the `div` element having the same `id`. The technique is from 1990's, you should not use that anymore.

Comment: Personally I'd log that as a bug, because that's a bad code smell.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, thank you very much. So the correct way was definitely using `blockElement` all along.

Comment: Yep. Maybe they have changed variable names, and forgotten to change all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is this block the same as blockElement? how?

Almost certainly, yes. `block` is an automatic global. In the browser, elements with an `id` are automatically made properties of the `window` object unless something else supercedes them; properties of that object are also global variables. Details of their being `window` properties are in [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). The fact the `window` object is also the JavaScript global object is covered somewhat subtly [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object). Properties of the global object being globals is covered [in the JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments).

Relying on that is generally a Bad Idea™, because:

- The global namespace is ***very*** crowded and the rules for which things supercede others are hard to remember. For instance, you won't find an automatic global for `<div id="name"></div>` because the global `name` means something else.
- It's quite difficult to read code relying on "magical" variables (as you've found).

As you've determined, in this case the author appears to have meant `blockElement` anyway. Using `block` there was either just a typo, or an original name of a variable he/she decided to rename later.

Comment: Kudos for linking the spec. I had no idea that was in the standard, maybe it's time the current standard deprecates this dumb "specification bug"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: It's the other way around, actually: The spec *gained* that (it never had it prior to HTML5) precise to codify and explain what browsers were doing.

Comment: Ugh, it never should have, in my opinion. Never let magic variables be a standard, that leads to very brittle and un-maintainable code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: The folks doing the "living standard" for HTML take a very, very pragmatic approach. They lead where they can, and codify and explain where necessary. Much better to have it written down than to leave it as an oral history. :-) We'll need a technology change to get rid of them, even JavaScript modules still suffer with The Globals Problem (just less so).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the detailed explanation and examples provided in [this blog post](http://2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html):

> The [HTML5 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) specifies that the `window` object must have a
>   property *key* whose value is *elem* if...
>
> - there is exactly one DOM element *elem* whose property `id` has the value *key*.
> - there is exactly one DOM element *elem* whose property `name` has the value *key*. *elem*’s tag must be one of: a, applet, area, embed, form,
>     frame, frameset, iframe, img, object.

In less technical terms, the browser creates a global variable for the unique `id` of your `div`. However, using it seems to be a bad practice and you should rely on something like `var block = document.getElementById('block');` instead to make sure no problems arise.